# Using python static class C#/Java style, scope difference errors

Tags: python, class, static

I have two files, namely game.py and map.py. The following simplified code resides in them:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

from datetime import *

from map import *

class Game:

    Scene = QGraphicsScene
    View = QGraphicsView


    @staticmethod
    def start():
        Game.App = QApplication(sys.argv)       
        Game.Scene=QGraphicsScene();    

        Game.Scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(Qt.green)));

        Game.View=QGraphicsView(Game.Scene);
        print Game
        map=Map()

        Game.App.exec_()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Game.start()
```

and file map.py:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from game import *
class Map(QObject):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Map,self).__init__(parent);
        print Game
        v=Game.View
        print v
        v.setWindowTitle("sth")
```

Running game.py results in

```
__main__.Game
game.Game
<class 'PyQt4.QtGui.QGraphicsView'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abiusx/workspace/borj/trunk/game.py", line 119, in <module>
    Game.start()
  File "/home/abiusx/workspace/borj/trunk/game.py", line 66, in start
    map=Map()
  File "/home/abiusx/workspace/borj/trunk/map.py", line 16, in __init__
    v.setWindowTitle("asb")
TypeError: QWidget.setWindowTitle(QString): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'
```

The problem is, the code in map.py that references Game.View, detects it as a class (as defined in class body) but not what is overwritted on it (an actual instance).
Also Game is known as **main**.Game in game.py but as game.Game in map.py

Could anyone help me?

Comment: The problem was circular referencing. solved it by changing dependency tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a file is read in Python, when it reaches a class definition it defines that class.

In my scenario, game and map both relied on each other. this is a well known circular reference problem in python.
I added another module, main.py, used game and map in it, and game in map. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

> the code in map.py that references Game.View, detects it as a class

That's because `View = QGraphicsView` sets it to a class. It only becomes an instance when you run `Game.start`. (To be honest, I don't understand why you're setting this class variable to a `class` object initially, or why the `Game` class exists at all.)

> Also Game is known as main.Game in game.py but as game.Game in map.py

The module name changes to `__main__` when you run a module as a script.

Comment: So how should I fix it? I want to have Java style static class, so everywhere in my whole code I could easily use Game.View or Game.Scene to reference it.

Comment: In Python, modules play the role that static classes have in Java. Put `View`, `Scene` and `start` at module scope.

Comment: How can I reference them then? Using the exact same method

Comment: `import game`, then use as `game.View` etc.

Comment: No difference, ends up with the same exact error! Please help